# Bash while множественное условие

Tags: linux, bash

Интересует перечисление условий через && в while , тк вот код который работает в if но не работает в while.

// Это работает

```
read item

if ! [ -z $item ] && ! [[ "$item" == *ok ]]
 then
  echo "succes"
fi
```

// Это не работает

```
read item

while [ -z $item ] && ! [[ "$item" == *ok ]]
 do
  echo "invalid"
  read item
done
```

Интересует способ через && или что - то подобное, без множественных вложений while внутрь другого.

Comment: у вас перед `[ -z $item ]` в if есть `!`, а в while - нет

Comment: zOMG, `man test` что ли?  `test -n $item -a $item != "ok"`.

Comment: kvm , наличие ! ничего не решает как я знаю , уже пробовал без него.

Answer (score 1):

У меня вот так работает, например:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

count1=10
count2=0

while [[ $count1 -gt 5 ]] && [[ $count2 -lt 3 ]] ; do
    let count1=count1-1
    let count2=count2+1
done
```

---

возможно будет полезно, на английском SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534595/bash-scripting-multiple-conditions-in-while-loop

Comment: как я прочитал из многих ресурсов, то while берет значение из последнего условия, вы уверены что работают оба условия?

Comment: @S1lllver это очень легко проверить! добавьте в цикле распечатку счетчиков: `echo "c1: ${count1}, c2: ${count2}"` и поиграйтесь с count1 и count2 :)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
while true
 do
  read item
  if ! [ -z $item ] && ! [[ "$item" == *ok ]]; then
    echo "success"
    break
  fi
  echo "invalid, try again"
done
```

Только ! расставьте логично, а то у вас условие то так, то эдак.